# Local system based timestamp on 00:00:00 of particular day

Tags: time, operating-system

How do i get time in seconds from epoch at 00:00:00 of a particular day on local machine.I want to trigger a service on 00:00:00 of a particular day and so i wanted to know time in seconds from epoch on local machine when system time reach to 00:00:00.
I have to do it using C language .
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

That's what the `mktime` function is for. See [the documentation here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html).

```
struct tm time_str;
time_str.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;  /* year minus 1900 */
time_str.tm_mon = 8 - 1;         /* month minus 1 */
time_str.tm_mday = 11;
time_str.tm_hour = 0;
time_str.tm_min = 0;
time_str.tm_sec = 0;
time_str.tm_isdst = -1;
time_t seconds_since_epoch = mktime(&time_str);
```